# Integrating JIRA Service Desk with PagerDuty

Tags: jira

I would like to create a PagerDuty incident every time a customer creates an issue of a certain type (Fault) on JIRA Service Desk. So I have created a JIRA user with the email address provided by PagerDuty, an incident was created when JIRA sent the invitation to PagerDuty, which seems to indicate that when JIRA sends an email, PagerDuty gets it. Then I added an automation rule (issue notifications did not work as I didn't find a way to send a notification only when an issue of a certain type is created), to notify my special user every time an issue is created with the Fault type.

[image: Automation rule to notify pagerduty user when issue is created with the Fault type]

But when I create an issue of this type, nothing seems to be sent to PagerDuty. I have tested sending an email directly to the email address of PagerDuty user and it worked. I have tested notifying another user when an issue is created in JIRA Service desk and it worked too. So I don't know what's wrong but I can't get the email to be sent to PagerDuty from JIRA Service Desk. Any idea of what I missed?

Comment: You should check out ngDesk instead as its totally free and has more features then pager duty. You can check it out here https://www.ngdesk.com